# nodejs socket.io GET http://domain/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LrTVonQ status of 404 when importing socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

My problem is simple I'm actually getting an error 404 when I'm trying to import socket.io on my web page. I'm using

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.3/socket.io.js"></script>
```

to import socket.io.

If I remove this line form my head tag, I'm fine but when it's there, I see in the dev tool the 404 error and my counter is not even working.

I am trying to make a live viewer count for one of my website but I never really use Node.js so this is why I have some trouble. Please forgive me if there is an error in my script.

For the serverside script, the file is called: viewercounter.js and this is the code

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var port = 8001;

server.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Server listening at port %d', port);
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

var count = 0
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    count++;
    socket.broadcast.emit('userupd', {
        numUsers: count
    });
    console.log(count);

    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        count--;
        socket.broadcast.emit('userupd', {
            numUsers: count
        });
        console.log(count);
    });
});
```

Then I placed the clientside script directly in my page instead of making a new file, I did not really see the point of it. Anyway, the file is called: index.php
and the code is at the end of the file just before the end of the body tag and there not other js before the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  var socket = io();

  socket.on('userupd', function (data) {
    $('.counter').html(data);
  });
});
```

**EDIT**

By looking more deeper, I've been able to understand that it's a XMLHttpRequest problem. In fact, when the socket.io code that I just imported try to perform xhr.send(this.data) the error appears. Anyone knows how I can solve this ?
https://gyazo.com/53f64081a92b449e157df76c6c570178

**EDIT2**

After changing the port in the file viewcounter.js. It looks like this:

```
// Setup basic express server
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var port = 80;

server.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Server listening at port %d', port);
});

// Routing
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

var count = 0
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    count++;
    socket.broadcast.emit('userupd', {
        numUsers: count
    });
    console.log('New user: ');

    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        count--;
        socket.broadcast.emit('userupd', {
            numUsers: count
        });
        console.log('Neg user:');
    });
   });
```

Comment: Well, the URL `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.3/socket.io.js` works perfectly fine from here.  So, if you're getting a 404 on that exact URL, then there was either a temporary glitch at the time you looked or there's a network problem from your end or you're mistaken about what is giving you a 404.  That URL appears to work just fine to me.  You need `socket.io.js` because that's the socket.io library that makes socket.io work in the browser.

Comment: I'm still getting the error. So I guest that it's network problem from my end. But again that would be very strange because I'm using a vps bought at OVH... In other word, I'm sure that it I'm getting the 404 error on the URL. https://gyazo.com/7760940ba93dce354a06c28993c076fb

Comment: Your 404 appears to be on this URL `http://goldenvision.ml/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LrVsppJ` which is an attempt to initiate a socket.io connection from the client to the server.  That means that the server is not properly listening for socket.io connections on that host and port.  It sure looks to me like your 404 URL is trying to make a socket.io connection on port 80, but your server is listening on port 8080. When you do `var socket = io();` in the client, what is the client webpage URL that that code is located in? What does the browser bar show as the active URL for the page?

Comment: the browser shows http://goldenvision.ml/index?game= and there is the id of a game

Comment: That's likely your problem then.  That page URL has no port number in it so it defaults to port 80, but your server is listening to port 8001.  When you do `var socket = io()`, that makes a request to the same host and port as the page URL that it is in.  Unless you have some server-side infrastructure (like a proxy) that redirects incoming requests to port 80 to go to port 8001, your socket.io server will not see any requests for port 80 and thus they will produce a 404.

Comment: Even if what you say seams absolutly logic and well thinked, I just change the port to 8080 but I'm still getting the error. https://gyazo.com/8879ccad0cbb3f24f1c1ec11356af21c

Comment: What exactly did you change because no port changed in the error you just posted?  The port for the socket.io server in the code you show in your question is 8001.

Comment: The variable port in the viewcounter.js. I tryed var port = 80; and var port = 8080; both did not worked

Comment: I'm not understanding your overall system layout.  What server is providing your `http://goldenvision.ml/index?game=` web page?  Where does that web page come from?  Is that coming from a PHP server running on port 80?  And, now you're trying to create a different server that can work for socket.io?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your web page is coming from an Apache web server on port 80 and you want to create a socket.io server in node.js on the **same host**, then you need to pick a new port for that socket.io server and when you connect to the socket.io server, you need to identify the port you want to connect to because the default will be port 80, but that's not where your socket.io server is.

I'd suggest using port `8001` like you originally had for your socket.io server.  Please change your node.js code back to that.

Then, you can change the socket.io code in your page from this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  var socket = io();

  socket.on('userupd', function (data) {
    $('.counter').html(data);
  });
});
</script>
```

to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  var url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + ":8001";
  var socket = io(url, {transports: ['websocket'], upgrade: false});

  socket.on('userupd', function (data) {
    $('.counter').html(data);
  });
});
</script>
```

This will connect socket.io to the same protocol and host as your web page, but a different port and it will use only a webSocket so you don't run into cross origin issues with socket.io's usual attempt to initiate a connection with Ajax polling.

If your socket.io server is actually on a different host than your Apache server, then you need to put that host in the URL rather than `window.location.hostname`.

Comment: Thanks ! It's working. Well, I dont get error now but it's not updating the counter. For that I think that I'll search on google but it's not getting the error so that's a very good news ! *EDIT* It's working perfercly but not at the first connection on the page, it actually update the number on the others pages but not on the last client that connect. SO ! BIG thanks ! Thanks you veeeeeeery much, you've been veeeery helpful ! And patient :)