# Nodejs "WebSocket is closed before the connection is established" socket.io espress

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I have this issus, which I never encountered and that every other post that I found didn't help me at all.

In fact, I'm using NodeJS with Express and Socket.io on a SSL protected website but I get this error: "WebSocket connection to 'wss://site.domain:8001/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established."

So I search on the Internet and I found a lot of intersting stuff and even people which had the exact same problem as me but nobody answer them and sometimes it was just not working.

I have 2 files, like normaly, I have the server file which is called "server.js" and the client file which is called "agent.php".

**server.js**

```
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');

var mysql = require('mysql');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('/var/www/html/site.domain/public_html/cert/domain.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/var/www/html/site.domain/public_html/cert/domain.pem')
};
var serverPort = 8001;

var server = https.createServer(options, app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});


var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "127.0.0.1",
  user: "user",
  password: "password",
  database: "dbname"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected to mysql!");
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log('new connection');
});

server.listen(serverPort, function() {
  console.log('server up and running at %s port', serverPort);
});
```

This result by writing in the console "server up and running at 8001 port" as expected. But "new connection" is not printed when you load the page because of the error I think.

**agent.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TERMINAL - AGENT</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/agent.css?version=<?php $v=rand(100,9999999999); echo $v;?>">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/main.css?version=<?php $v=rand(100,9999999999); echo $v;?>">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="icon" href="/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cairo|Pontano+Sans:400,600|Rajdhani:400,600|Teko:400,600|Titillium+Web:400,600|Exo:400,600|Open+Sans+Condensed:400,600|sans-serif|Anton:400,600|VT323|Grand+Hotel|Anonymous+Pro:400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.3/socket.io.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    *A lot of html stuff which is not important at all*

    <script type="text/javascript">
      <?= 'var mat = '.htmlspecialchars($_GET['mat']).';' ?>
      $( document ).ready(function (){
        var url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + ":8001";
        var socket = io(url, {transports: ['websocket'], upgrade: false});

      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And that result with the error. I really not know what to do at this point, I have used all my knowledge and I have search a lot also.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that you have the same version of socket.io on client and server because when they are mismatched, it will exhibit the exact same symptoms you describe.  If you use `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>` for the client-side socket.io library, then you will always get the right version as it will be served automatically by the socket.io server.

Comment: Also, does `var socket = io();` work or does it have the same problem?

Comment: Well, I knew of /socket.io/socket.io.js but I never get it to work, in fact I always get 3 errors when using that. 1. 404 on /socket.io/socket.io.js   2. io is not defined   3. io is not defined      https://gyazo.com/486da3a68beef01cd1abd38012cc7cf5
You can see that the 404 (GET url) is on page "civil" instead of "agent" but it's a copy of "agent"

Comment: Is your web page coming from the same server that your socket.io server is on?  If you're connecting to the same host, then `/socket.io/socket.io.js` should work just fine.  Or are you trying to connect to some different host?  Also, did you check the socket.io versions from my first comment?

Comment: I checked the version and both the server and the client (when importing) and it's not working. I am using the client and the server on the same server which is a VPS rented by ovh and also var socket = io(); didn't solve anything.

Comment: Does your VPS support webSocket connections?

Comment: How is agent.php served?  Is it coming from your Express server (your code does not show this)?  Or from some other server?  And, why is it named `.php`?  Is there a PHP server involved here somewhere?

Comment: There is PHP involved, the server is up and running for any php and in the page agent.php there is also some php about the GET variables and to check them in the mysql database. The agent.php is hosted on the server and you access it via your browser by connecting to the website. The actual structure of my files are: 
https://gyazo.com/3d1a9f5f870a35559080dbe673e04bd5

Comment: OK, that finally explains why `/socket.io/socket.io.js` doesn't work.  You're not loading the current page from Express.  You're loading that from a PHP server and Express is on a different port.  Is your PHP server also https?  I"d suggest you look at the network tab in the Chrome debugger when this page loads and see what you can learn from that.  Pay particular attention to what network traffic there is for the socket.io connection and errors returned.

Comment: Well, I'm not so sure of how to interpret this Network tab and how to see the port. But I see that socket.io.js get an 404 error when I use `/socket.io/socket.io.js` but it's a status code 200 when I use the cdn. Anyway, here is what I got, sorry, I'm asking you a lot. NOt so sure that it's important to mention but in the civil.php I have only one php line about the get and noting else, also the server is apache2 runing an a debian 8 vps on which I did a apt-get install of the php stuff.

https://gyazo.com/5eee2fd304c6dc01563597c3e4d655e6
https://gyazo.com/cbac21891dff95d2467735123d6171b0

Comment: And also, I tryed to only put `var socket = io();` but it's not working and also i'm using the code you've given me in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45203612/nodejs-socket-io-get-http-domain-socket-io-eio-3transport-pollingt-lrtvonq be cause it was working well. And for information I guess that it support webSocket connection because it,s the same exact server that I was using that time, note that my older nodejs server is not online at this moment

Comment: You have multiple servers with both node.js/Express and Apache/PHP involved.  I really have no idea how your system is laid out.  Of course, `/socket.io/socket.io.js` and `var socket = io()` don't work if your express server is not the same host and port and protocol that the web page came from.  Both of those are designed to contact the same host. port and protocol that the web page came from.  Until I understand exactly what host, port and protocol all servers are on and what web pages come from what server, I can't really help any further.

Comment: Ok thanks for trying. But I still don't understand why is my older website working and this one not because the only thing I did between the developement of this one and the old one is to create a new website. Which has basicaly the same architecture, same server, same everything but the html code in the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found out what was my problem ! I was using cloudflare to make the site more secure and to handle the https. So I disabled all the things with CloudFlare and now it working... but only in non-secure. I set-up the SSL stuff in apache and it is working fine in a non-nodejs page but with nodejs it's not working. So one problem resolved ! I hope that it help everyone that may encounter the same problem as me !